# How to Store a VARIANT

Tags: c++, windows, com

I need to store a VARIANT of type bstr in a stl vector. I'm not sure how should I store VARIANT type in vector.

```
vector<VARIANT> vec_MyVec;

    VARIANT var_Temp;
    VariantInit(&var_Temp);
    var_Temp.vt = VT_BSTR
    var_Temp.bstrVal = SysAllocString("Test");

vec_MyVec.push_back(var_Temp);
```

Is this implementation cause a memory leak ? What would be the best way to store VARIANTS ?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "Is this implementation cause a memory leak?" The way you are storing the VARIANT is fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think a copy of VARIANT is stored in the vector. Then SysAllocString() cause a memory leak, since I'm not freering my original object. But I'm not sure about it. That's why I need help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're leaking memory.

Whenever you allocate memory with the `SysAllocString` family, you must either free it using `SysFreeString` or pass it to something that will take responsibility for freeing it. The VARIANT type does not clean up its own memory.

You have a couple of options for fixing it:

- Use `CComVariant` or `variant_t`. It provides an operator=, copy constructors and a destructor that manage the memory for you. The drawback to storing them in a vector is that temporary copies will be created and destroyed (the same as if you'd stored std::string). This is the easiest, and my preferred, solution.
- Call `SysFreeString` on every string in `vec_MyVec` when you're finished. This is more efficient but also much more error prone and difficult to do correctly, especially when considering exception safety.
- Store a vector of `std::tr1::shared_ptr<CComVariant>`, this will prevent temporary copies being created, but you'll have the overhead of reference counting instead.